# How would I analyze the change in bacterial populations in different nutrient solutions?

Tags: regression, experiment-design

I am planning an experiment and have trouble finding out the best method of analyzing the data, I would like to do power analysis beforehand.

I have 6 bottles, 3 with nutrient solution A, and 3 with solution B (3 replicates each). In each bottle I will add 3 bacterial species, the same amount of cells per species (for example, 100 cells of each). Then I wait time t, maybe a week, and then take each bottle, take out a small sample, like 1 ml, and count how many bacteria of each species there are.

The questions I would like to answer:
Is there a difference between the end time point and the start for each of the different solutions?
Is there a different between the two solutions at the end time point?

I have tried to find out what would be the best way to analyze this, but just get more confused the more I read. There are various methods to compare species communities, but these seem to be used more with large numbers of species and overly complicated. Can I just use an ANOVA?

Also, I may add more time points in between start and end. Could I use a regression method in that case (GLM?)?

Example of what the data may look like below.

```
            nsA1    nsA2    nsA3    nsB1    nsB2    nsB3
    bact1   100     100     100     100     100     100
t0  bact2   100     100     100     100     100     100
    bact3   100     100     100     100     100     100

    bact1   80      85      79      10      11      15
t1  bact2   150     120     131     133     142     136
    bact3   112     105     103     52      48      49
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Microbiologists commonly use log(count) to achieve near Normality.
2. Your example t0 values are constant, so can be neglected.

That suggests a simple 2-way ANOVA of log(t1 counts) by bact and solution. I'd be tempted to include an interaction term and would definitely look at the residuals to confirm (approximate) Normality.

If you include more time points I suppose you *could* regress log(count) on time as influenced by bact and solution. However the dependence of log(count) on time is usually far from rectilinear and commonly uses non-linear fitting of quite "difficult" sigmoid functions. If you have only a few time points I'd be tempted to include time as a factor leading to a 3-way ANOVA.

Comment: Thanks! I googled for log transforming count data, and the first hit is a paper titled "Do not log-transform count data" ;). They suggest a Poisson or negative binominal based GLM instead.
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00021.x/full

Comment: @ShellfishGene Hmmm. Microbial counts are discrete which can motivate a discrete distribution at low numbers. If you can assume perfect mixing then Poisson is reasonable. A generalised Poisson such as a negative binomial is more generally applicable, e.g. see http://www.ilsi.org/Europe/Publications/Microbial%20Distribution%202010.pdf especially p25. "All models are wrong ..."; if numbers are high enough that the probability of a zero is negligible then a lognormal distribution can be useful. Add "microbiology" to your search and see how widely - and successfully - it is used.